# Assert fails in Python

Tags: python, hex, tornado, assert

I have this code:

```
/server/frontend/wsn.py
Line 866:        
    netid = hextransform(int(nid), 16)

Line 156: 
    def hextransform(data, length):
        data = hex(data)[2:]
        assert(len(data) <= length)
        # zero-padding
        data = ('0' * (length - len(data))) + data
        # Swap 'bytes' in the network ID
        data = list(data)
        for i in range(0, length, 2):
            tmp = data[i]
            data[i] = data[i + 1]
            data[i + 1] = tmp
        # Reverse the whole string (TODO: CHECK) 
        data.reverse()
        #data = "".join(data)
        return data
```

My problem is when I have a `nid = 15579202759033880576` for example. Is it too long?

The error I receive from Tornado is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 988, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1739, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./wsn.py", line 866, in get
    netid = hextransform(int(nid), 16)
  File "./wsn.py", line 158, in hextransform
    assert(len(data) <= length)
AssertionError
```

But `netid` in hex is  `0xd834725e00000000` and `len(nid) = 16`.

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You can add a message to the `assert`: `assert len(data) <= length, '{!r}, {}'.format(data, length)` to help debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'L' from the `hex(int(num))` is your problem:

```
>>> hex(int(15579202759033880576))[2:]
'd834725e00000000L'   <-- 17 with the L
```

The quickest fix for this is just to update your substring chop to get rid of that L as well:

```
data = hex(data)[2:].split('L')[0]
```

This will split your string around the L (if present) and give you the hex part. It's safe since 'L' isn't a hex character so it will only show up if you have a long string.

Comment: But if the nid is short with this solution I have another problem?

Comment: @sharkbait - Good point, I was thinking all of your `nid`s were long for some reason. I updated to accommodate for short ones.

Answer (score 2):

Python adds a `L` for long numbers:

```
>>> hex(int(15579202759033880576))
'0xd834725e00000000L'
```

adding one more character. Use a different method to create a hex number:

```
format(data, '016x')
```

instead. The [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) lets you use the [format spec mini language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) to transform your data; `x` is a lower-cased hex representation in this case, and you don't need to slice anything:

```
>>> format(15579202759033880576, '016x')
'd834725e00000000'
```

Note the 016 in the format there; if your number is smaller than 16 hex digits, it'll be padded with zeros for you:

```
>>> format(1557920, '016x')
'000000000017c5a0'
```

Your byte swapping can be done more easily too; python supports multiple assignments letting you swap two values without the need for a temporary variable:

```
for i in range(0, length, 2):
    data[i], data[i + 1] = data[i + 1], data[i]
```

Thus, your `hextransform` method can be simplified to:

```
def hextransform(data, length):
    data = format(data, '0{0}x'.format(length))
    assert(len(data) == length), '{0!r}, {1}'.format(data, length)
    # Swap 'bytes' in the network ID
    data = list(data)
    for i in range(0, length, 2):
        data[i], data[i + 1] = data[i + 1], data[i]
    data.reverse()
    return data
```

resulting in:

```
>>> hextransform(15579202759033880576, 16)
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', 'e', '7', '2', '3', '4', 'd', '8']
```